# Build LINQ query from a string

Tags: c#, linq

I have string

```
var query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("myDb.Holiday.FirstOrDefault()");
```

Can I generate the `linq` query from this?

Comment: I hve a feeling that you will need to either use an existing, 3rd party library or write your own parser

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to do it you have to write a parser yourself.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet) awnser solves the linq OrderBy from string and from there you should be able to implement the rest of the functions you require.

[This](http://aonnull.blogspot.se/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html) is a good implementation of that awnser.